# Azure Pipelines build task test fail with error: "Must initialize"

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-devops, mocha.js, azure-pipelines-build-task

when I invoke index.js directly using node, it works, but when I run mocha tests, the task fails with "Must initialize" error message.

my tasks index.ts looks like this:

```
import * as path from "path";
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');
import trm = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner');
import os = require('os');

async function run() {
    try {
        const libmanJson = tl.getPathInput('libmanjson', true, true); //this throws
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
    }
}
```

[mocha tests](https://github.com/Liero/libman-vsts-extension/tree/f1d6cf94eb34607fb1c4069e4608bf87fe323e99/libmantask/tests) are copied from here: [learn.microsoft.com: Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops#step-2-unit-testing-your-task-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, resolved by providing Answers to the TaskMockRunner

```
let a: ma.TaskLibAnswers = <ma.TaskLibAnswers>{
    "which": {
        "echo": "/mocked/tools/echo"
    },
    "exec": {
        "/mocked/tools/echo Hello, from task!": {
            "code": 0,
            "stdout": "atool output here",
            "stderr": "atool with this stderr output"            
        }
    }
};
tmr.setAnswers(a)
```